# Changing the scope of a captured block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I want to capture blocks (with an associated name), but without any change in the scope in which they are written. The code below has two ways of capturing a block (`capt_a` and `capt_b`). `capt_a` works fine and I'd like `capt_b` to work the same way. Is it possible to modify `capt_b` so that the effect is the same as `capt_a`?

```
class Capturer
  attr_reader :method, :block

  def capt_a
    yield self
    self
  end

  def capt_b(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
    self
  end

  def method_missing(method, &block)
    @method = method
    @block = block
  end
end

# Example:
a = Capturer.new.capt_a{|capt| capt.foo{self} }.block
b = Capturer.new.capt_b{ foo{self} }.block

a.call # => main
b.call # => #<Capturer:0x000001008fb5c8 @method=:foo, @block=#<Proc:0x000001008fb500@temp.rb:23>>
       # I would like 'main'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research in the direction @bioneuralnet suggested, it's possible to create a new `Proc` doing a new `instance_eval` to restore the context. The `binding` of the initial block is used to get the initial `self`. So here is a (somewhat ugly) solution:

```
  def capture_b(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
    the_desired_self = block.binding.eval("self")
    bk = @block
    @block = Proc.new{ the_desired_self.instance_eval(&bk) }
    self
  end
```

It's not perfect, as it will be slower and since the original block won't be `==` to the resulting block; maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can find is:

```
m = self
b = Capturer.new.capt_b{ foo{m} }.block
```

I might very well be wrong, but I believe using instance_eval is going to evaluate any use of "self" as the object you're evaluating against. Assigning "main" as a variable, I believe, is the only way to ensure it is used.

Comment: My code was just an example; it's not just `self` but the whole context that I'd like to restore.

Comment: In my above example, calling `m.instance_eval do ...` would "restore" that context. Is that what you mean? You may also find the Binding class of use. http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Binding.html#M000022 I just ran across it.

Comment: Indeed, doing an `instance_eval` should (more or less) restore the right context. I've posted solution that shows this. Thanks